# javaScript file loads in wrong order

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I'm new to javaScript and am trying to load a CSV or TXT file into the browser.

When the file is selected an event handler displays the file name and details, once the user hits the load button the script should double check the file extension, load the file then carry out some further checks on the file.

My problem is that the file load function seems to always be called last meaning the other checks happen first.

The file is held here: http://bananamountain.net/project/20140703pm/file-loader2.html

Code pasted below:

```
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        // Check for the various File API support.
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }

    </script>
    <h3>File Load test</h3>
    <p>Use only test-data-csv.csv just now</p>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required="required" accept=".csv, .txt" />
    <button onclick="handleFileLoad()">Load button</button>

    <output id="list"></output>

    <script>

        // global variables
        var content;
        var fileName;
        var splitString = ",";
        var rows = new Array();
        var headerRow = new Array();
        var values = new Array();

        function handleFileLoad() {
            //var suitableFileType = checkFileType();
            //document.write("<strong>Suitable file type: " + suitableFileType + "</strong><br />");


            loadFile();
            var suitableContent = checkFileContent();
            document.write("<strong>Suitable file content: " + suitableContent + "</strong><br />");


        }


        function checkFileType() {      
            document.write("inside checkFileType<br/>");
            // var testFile = fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase();
            //    document.write("file extension is '" + testFile+ "'<br />");

            if ((fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() === "CSV")) { 
                document.write('suitable file selected<br/>');
                return (true);
            } else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() === "TXT") {
                document.write('suitable file selected<br/>');
                return (true);
            }else {
                document.write('Invalid file format! \nPlease select a suitable .txt or .csv file<br/>');
                return (false);
            }

        }   // end of checkFileType - tested WORKING

        function loadFile() {

            //  checkFileType();

            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var link_reg = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/i;
            reader.onload = function(file) {
                // content = reader.result;
                content = file.target.result;
                rows = file.target.result.split(/[\r\n|\n]+/);
                for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                    document.write("row found at line " + i + " is " + rows[i] +".<br/>");
                }
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
            /*
            var suitableFileType = checkFileType();
            document.write("<strong>Suitable file type: " + suitableFileType + "</strong><br />");

            var suitableContent = checkFileContent();
            document.write("<strong>Suitable file content: " + suitableContent + "</strong><br />");

            var splitStringFound = getSplitString();
            document.write("<strong>Split string found: " + splitStringFound + "</strong><br />");
            document.write("<strong>Split String: " + splitString + "</strong><br/>");

            var replacedHeaders = checkHeaderRow();
            document.write("<strong>Header row complete<br />" + replacedHeaders +" headers replaced</strong><br/>");

            document.write(content);

            document.write(fileName);
            document.write(splitString);
            document.write(rows);
            document.write( headerRow);
            document.write(values);*/
            return;
        }


        function checkFileContent() {

            document.write("inside check file content<br/>");
            // check for file content
            // identifies blank lines and deletes them

            // checking content of rows
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
                document.write ("Row " + i + " is " + rows[i]);
            }
            var filteredArr = rows.filter(function (val) {
                return !(val === "" || typeof val == "undefined" || val === null || val === ",," || val === "\t\t");
            });

            // identifies empty file (e.g. all blank lines deleted)
            if (filteredArr.length === 0) {
                document.write("Empty file - no data found <br/>");
                rows = filteredArr;
                return false;
                // check for row deletions
            } else if (rows.length < filteredArr.length) {
                rows = filteredArr;
                document.write("blank rows deleted - " + (rows.length - filteredArr.length) + " rows remaining. <br/>");
                return ("deletions");
            } else {
                document.write("No blank rows <br/>");
                return true;
            }
        }       // end of check file content - empty file tested, file with one line tested

        function checkHeaderRow() {
            // check for header row
            // words in first non-empty row
            var replaceCount = 0;
            var checkArray = rows[0].split(splitString);

            for (var i = 1; i < checkArray.length; i++) {
                // start at array[1] as array[0] not likely to be a header value
                // loop through inserting non numeric values into headerRow array
                if (isNaN(checkArray[i])) {
                    headerRow[i - 1] = checkArray[i];
                    // need a flag to remove this from file once it has been done
                    replaceCount++;
                } else {
                    headerRow[i - 1] = "Risk " + i;
                }
            }
            // if non numeric values in array[1] delete rows[0]
            // so the header row is not included with the data set
            if (isNaN(checkArray[1])) {
                rows[0] = null;
            }
            return (replaceCount);
        }  // end of checkHeaderRow works for all non-numeric, all numeric and mixed


        function getSplitString() {

            // call countCharacter to return count of comma and tab characters in first five lines
            var tabCount =  countCharacter("\t");
            var commaCount = countCharacter(",");

            // compare tabCount and commaCount values
            if (tabCount === 0 && commaCount === 0) {
                document.write("Cannot detect the value seperator,\n please ammend file to seperate values with tabs or commas");
                return false;
            }
            else if (tabCount === commaCount) {
                splitString = prompt("Cannot detect the value seperator,\n please input \"\\t\" for tabs or \",\" for commas");
                if ((splitString === null) || (splitString != '\t') || (splitString != ',')) {
                    document.write("please check file and try again<br/>");
                    splitString = ',';
                    return false;  
                }   // NOT WORKING
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (tabCount>commaCount) {
                splitString = "\t";
                if (commaCount!=0) {
                    document.write("tab character selected as value seperator.<br/>");
                    // alert as this may not be the case
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                splitString=",";
                if (tabCount!=0){
                    document.write("tab character selected as value seperator.<br/>");
                    // alert as this may not be the case
                }
                return true;
            }
        }       // end of getSplitString - NOT FULLY WORKING


        function splitRows() {
            // what if rows is now empty? (e.g. header row only in file)
            if (rows[0] != null) {
                for (var i=0; i<rows.length;i++) {
                    values.push(rows[i].split(splitString));
                }
                return values;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }  // end of splitRows fully working

        function checkEmptyCells () {


            for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
                for (var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++)
                    if (!((values[i][j] === "") || (typeof values[i][j] == "undefined") || (values[i][j] === null) || (values[i][j] === ",,") || (values[i][j] === "\t\t"))) {
                        // remove line values[i][j]
                        document.write("in here");
                    }
            }
        }   // NOT FININSHED - STOPPED HERE



        function countCharacter (character) {
            // count the instances of a specified character over first 5 lines (or length of rows array)
            // number of rows to loop through 
            var loopCount=0;
            var characterCount=0;

            if (rows.length < 5) {
                loopCount = rows.length;
            } else {
                loopCount = 5;
            }
            for (var count=0; count < loopCount; count++) {
                characterCount += rows[count].split(character).length-1;

            }
            return characterCount;
        }  // End of countCharacter - WORKING - TESTED







        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

            // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
            var output = [];
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {     // THIS IS NOT NEEDING TO BE IN A LOOP
                output.push('<strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> ', ' - ',
                            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                            '');
                fileName = escape(f.name);
            }
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<div class="file-name">' + output.join('') + '</div>';
        }

        document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try using jQuery's document.ready function to ensure your scripts load after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all I think I asked the question wrong and it was for that reason that there were limited responses.  I'm adding the answer so that if anyone has the same issue and comes across this that it can help them.

The problem was not in the html file loading but a file being loaded through javascript.  The script carried out some checks on the file, loaded the file and then carried out further checks on the contents of the file.

This was all happening correctly however javascript does a thing called asyncronious loading where it calls the functions in turn but moves to the next function before the current function has finished doing what it is doing.

Imagine you go to a bar, order drinks, pay for your drinks and go to your table.  Javascript would do this but without the normal pauses of waiting to get served, the useing of the drinks and getting change.

Essentially my code was going back to the table without drinks (or checking the contents of the file without it finishing loading).

To fix it I put a time out in, this probably isn't the best as the load speed will depend on the size of the file.  However it works for just now and allows me to get on with other stuff.

A snippet of the working code is as follows:
{
function handleFileLoad() {

```
            if (checkFileType()) {
                values = [];
                loadFile();
            } else {
                alert("Invalid file format! \nPlease select a suitable .txt or .csv file<br/>");
                return;
            }

            //setTimeout(fileContentChecks(), 1000);

            if (!setTimeout(fileContentChecks(), 1000)) {
                return;
            } else {
                setData(); //PROBABLY PUT THESE IN A FUNCTION OR TWO
                setComboLists(); //SO THESE CAN BE CALLED LATER TO UPDATE PAGE
                UpdateAssetList();
                UpdateXAxisList();
                UpdateYAxisList();
                UpdateTable();
            }
        }


        function checkFileType() { // CHECK FILE NAME EXTENSION

            if ((fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() === "CSV")) {
                return (true);
            } else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() === "TXT") {
                return (true);
            } else {
                return (false);
            }
        } // end of checkFileType - tested WORKING


        function loadFile() { // LOADS FILE AND SPLITS INTO ROWS

            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var link_reg = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/i;
            reader.onload = function(file) {

                content = file.target.result;
                rows = file.target.result.split(/[\r\n|\n]+/);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
            // NEEDS TIMEOUT HERE.....
            return;
        } // end of loadFile - TESTED WORKS WHEN STEPPING THROUGH - NEEDS TIMEOUT

        function fileContentChecks() {
            if (checkFileContent()) {
                if (getSplitString()) {
                    checkHeaderRow();
                } else {
                    alert("Seperator value not found"); // not sure if this is required?
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                alert("File contents not verified, please check file and try again.");
                return false;
            }
```